# Android Store JSON and Importing Data

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to store large chunks of data as JSON in the assets folder and then import it into the Database on Boot/First Run.

Is this a best practice ? Which other way can i achieve this ? 
Could you share some articles regarding database on Android

Comment: Why don't you just save into the assets folder the SQL dump you want to import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a best practice ?

You might just package a database in assets and save yourself the transaction time of doing the imports. See [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) for an implementation of this.

Comment: i came across someone who tried doing this tell there will be issues with the version. is it true ?

Comment: @HarshaMV: I am not aware of problems with `SQLiteAssetHelper`. Hopefully the "someone" filed an issue on that project's issue tracker, and hopefully that issue has been repaired.